# log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger in jboss6

Tags: java, jboss6.x

I am trying to deploy application server in jboss6 when i start the jboss it work fine but when i send the request from client to server it will give  error **ERROR: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.cdac.AsyncResponseComponent.PrepareSubmitResponse).** error so please help me.

my server.log is given below.

```
**Server.log**

2012-05-30 16:30:24,490 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (Thread-2) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-7001
2012-05-30 16:30:24,497 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol] (Thread-2) Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
2012-05-30 16:30:24,505 INFO  [org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer] (Thread-2) JBossAS [6.0.0.Final "Neo"] Started in 3m:32s:844ms

2012-05-30 16:33:51,904 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) BusinessClass::sendResponse Starts...
2012-05-30 16:33:51,908 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) Got Initial Context
2012-05-30 16:33:52,156 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) BusinessClass::sendResponse Starts...
2012-05-30 16:33:52,156 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) Got Home object
2012-05-30 16:33:52,475 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) Got Remote object
2012-05-30 16:33:52,476 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) Hi 1
2012-05-30 16:33:52,613 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) Hi 2
2012-05-30 16:33:52,613 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) calling EJB
2012-05-30 16:33:52,614 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) Hi 3
2012-05-30 16:33:53,658 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  i am in bean 
**2012-05-30 16:33:53,867 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.cdac.AsyncResponseComponent.PrepareSubmitResponse).
2012-05-30 16:33:53,867 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.**
2012-05-30 16:33:53,868 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
2012-05-30 16:33:54,327 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) Unexpected Error in method: public abstract com.cdac.messages.async.ReturnResponse com.cdac.AsyncSPResponse.SPResponseEJBRemote.makeSubmitResponse(com.cdac.messages.async.CommitResponse) throws java.rmi.RemoteException,org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException,java.lang.Exception: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.TypeStore.add_element_user(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/impl/values/TypeStoreUser;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, in/gov/mit/www/egov/schema/nsdg/spi/impl/SubmitDocumentDocument1Impl, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/values/TypeStore, have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/namespace/QName used in the signature
    at in.gov.mit.www.egov.schema.nsdg.spi.impl.SubmitDocumentDocument1Impl.addNewSubmitDocument(SubmitDocumentDocument1Impl.java:72) [:]
    at com.cdac.AsyncResponseComponent.PrepareSubmitResponse.processSubmitResponse(PrepareSubmitResponse.java:74) [:]
    at com.cdac.AsyncSPResponse.SPResponseEJBBean.makeSubmitResponse(SPResponseEJBBean.java:74) [:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_30]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_30]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_30]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_30]
    at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:386) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:233) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:156) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invoke(CallValidationInterceptor.java:63) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:121) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptorBMT.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptorBMT.java:173) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorBMT.invoke(TxInterceptorBMT.java:77) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:173) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.process(SecurityInterceptor.java:228) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:211) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.process(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:97) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.invoke(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:81) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:138) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:650) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:1072) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_30]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_30]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_30]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_30]
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker$MBeanServerAction.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:169) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:118) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invokeLocalMarshalled(InvokerInterceptor.java:295) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.MarshallingInvokerInterceptor.invoke(MarshallingInvokerInterceptor.java:61) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.proxy.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:61) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.proxy.ejb.SecurityContextInterceptor.invoke(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:64) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.proxy.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:68) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.proxy.ejb.StatelessSessionInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInterceptor.java:112) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:101) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at $Proxy148.makeSubmitResponse(Unknown Source) at org.apache.jsp.response_jsp._jspService(response_jsp.java:149)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_30]

2012-05-30 16:33:54,419 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) java.rmi.ServerError: Unexpected Error; nested exception is: 
2012-05-30 16:33:54,420 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.TypeStore.add_element_user(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/impl/values/TypeStoreUser;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, in/gov/mit/www/egov/schema/nsdg/spi/impl/SubmitDocumentDocument1Impl, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/values/TypeStore, have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/namespace/QName used in the signature
2012-05-30 16:33:54,421 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.handleException(LogInterceptor.java:434)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,421 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:209)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,422 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:138)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,423 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:650)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,424 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:1072)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,424 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,424 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,425 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,425 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,426 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,426 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,426 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,427 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,427 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,428 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker$MBeanServerAction.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:169)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,428 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:118)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,428 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invokeLocalMarshalled(InvokerInterceptor.java:295)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,429 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.MarshallingInvokerInterceptor.invoke(MarshallingInvokerInterceptor.java:61)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,429 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.proxy.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:61)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,430 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.proxy.ejb.SecurityContextInterceptor.invoke(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:64)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,430 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.proxy.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:68)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,431 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.proxy.ejb.StatelessSessionInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInterceptor.java:112)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,431 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:101)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,431 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at $Proxy148.makeSubmitResponse(Unknown Source)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,431 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.jsp.response_jsp._jspService(response_jsp.java:149)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,432 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,432 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,432 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,433 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,433 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,433 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,434 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,434 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,434 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,434 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,435 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,435 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,435 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,436 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,436 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,436 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,436 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,437 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,437 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,437 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,438 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,438 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,438 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,439 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,439 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,439 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.TypeStore.add_element_user(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/impl/values/TypeStoreUser;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, in/gov/mit/www/egov/schema/nsdg/spi/impl/SubmitDocumentDocument1Impl, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/values/TypeStore, have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/namespace/QName used in the signature
2012-05-30 16:33:54,440 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at in.gov.mit.www.egov.schema.nsdg.spi.impl.SubmitDocumentDocument1Impl.addNewSubmitDocument(SubmitDocumentDocument1Impl.java:72)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,440 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at com.cdac.AsyncResponseComponent.PrepareSubmitResponse.processSubmitResponse(PrepareSubmitResponse.java:74)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,440 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at com.cdac.AsyncSPResponse.SPResponseEJBBean.makeSubmitResponse(SPResponseEJBBean.java:74)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,440 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,441 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,441 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,441 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,442 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:386)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,442 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:233)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,443 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:156)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,443 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invoke(CallValidationInterceptor.java:63)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,443 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:121)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,443 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptorBMT.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptorBMT.java:173)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,444 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorBMT.invoke(TxInterceptorBMT.java:77)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,444 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:173)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,444 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.process(SecurityInterceptor.java:228)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,445 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:211)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,445 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.process(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:97)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,445 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.invoke(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,447 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205)
2012-05-30 16:33:54,447 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1)  ... 48 more




----------
## Heading ##


if any one have some time please help me thanks.
```

Comment: It only means that the `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` isn't available to the invoked code which gets called when you send request from client to server.

Comment: so where is add log4j.xml or log4j.properties in jboss because i have only .war file. please give me a good suggestion.thanks

Comment: It normally goes into the classpath. Try putting it inside `WEB-INF/classes` of your webapp.

Comment: when i set classpath after that i run the jboss but error is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your log4j.properties/xml in your app classpath, or set a jndi resource on the server (say, "log4jUrl") that points to the location where that file is, then lookup for that url and configure your logger:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(yourUrl)
```

Comment: when i set classpath after that i run the jboss but error is same.

Comment: Have you configured your logger with PropertyConfigurator? Is there a proper appender like `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender` in your properties file?